# Bug in MS Graph? Access Denied via Microsoft Graph: /users/{userID}/mailfolders/inbox/messagerules despite permissions, consent and delegation.

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-security

I'm wondering if we just found a bug in the MS Graph API. I'm trying to access a different user's inbox mail rules via MS Graph. Here's what I did:

1.) Registered an application on the V1 Azure AD Endpoint, with ALL delegated permissions (including MailBoxSettings.Read and MailBoxSettings.ReadWrite)
2.) Granted access to the application using a global admin account 
3.) Got a Graph Bearer Token for the tenant & proper permissions: 
[image: Bearer Token including scopes for mailbox settings]
4.) Delegated mailbox access (full access) to my Global Admin account in Exchange Online settings: 
[image: Global Admin with Full Access on user's mailbox]
5.) Verified that I have access to the users inbox via Graph: 
[image: accessing the user's inbox: no problem]
6.) Attempting to list messagerules for this user fails: 
[image: Listing message rules fails in spite of proper permissions]

Note that retrieving the current (global admin) user's mail rules works without an issue: 
GET /https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messageRules

This tells me that there is probably a bug in MS Graph - or am I maybe missing something?

Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, and I have get the same error. As my understand, we can not get the other's email rules. If you want to use this case, we can submit this issue on the [github Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues)

Answer (score 0):

To read other users emaill inbox you need Application Type permission set rather than Delegated access. 
Follow this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service